# Split comma-separated values

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio 2005 and C# 2.0, and I am trying to split a comma-separated string using the `string.Split` function and a lambda expression as follows:

```
string s = "a,b, b, c";
string[] values = s.Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
```

I get an error saying that the expression is not recognized -- how can I resolve this?

Comment: add more details. More detail means better chance to get an answer

Comment: You cannot use Lambdas in C# 2. Those were added in C# 3.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

.NET 2.0 does not support LINQ - [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674706/linq-in-framework-2-0.);
But you can create a 3.5 project in VS2005 - [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91d2f211-8bf6-4749-9732-e78e63568994/linq-and-visual-studio-2005?forum=linqtosql)

Without lambda support, you'll need to do something like this:

```
string s = "a,b, b, c";
string[] values = s.Split(',');
for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
   values[i] = values[i].Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

.NET 2.0 does not use lambda expressions.  You need to compile to .NET 3.0 to use them.

Comment: 3.5 if he wants to use [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: It's not a matter of .NET supporting lambda expressions. It's a matter of C# 2 not supporting lambda expressions. It's perfectly feasible to use lambda expressions in code targeting .NET 2.0, so long as you build with a C# 3+ compiler. And there are LINQ to OBjects implementations available for .NET 2 as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet Very good point, Jon -- I guess we aren't really answering his question. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: As Jon said, C# 2.0 is the problem, *not* .NET 2.0. Lambda expressions are a feature of the language, not the runtime.

Answer (score 7):

A way to do this without Linq & Lambdas

```
string source = "a,b, b, c";
string[] items = source.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: except, I think you then lose spaces within elements, so splitting "a b, c d" would give you "a", "b", "c", "d" rather than "a b", "c d"

Answer (score 3):

Lamba expression aren't included in c# 2.0

maybe you could refert to [this post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619930/how-do-i-rewrite-a-lambda-expression-in-c-sharp-2-0)

Answer (score 3):

Split a Textbox value separated by comma and count the total number of values in text and splitted values are shown in ritchTextBox.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "";
        richTextBox1.Text = "";

        string strText = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        string[] strArr = strText.Split(',');
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
        {
            count++;
        }
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += strArr[i].Trim() + "\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) (MIT Licensed) to add support for lambda expressions to C# 2.0:

> With Studio's multi-targeting and LINQBridge, you'll be able to write
>   local (LINQ to Objects) queries using the full power of the C# 3.0
>   compiler—and yet your programs will require only Framework 2.0.

Comment: He is using Visual Studio 2005 and therefore does not have access to the C# 3.0 compiler, and therefore can't compile lambda expressions no matter what.