# Parsing String Data in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have a question about parsing data in C#.
I have a string that starts with the $ sign and ends with the $ sign and contains 5 different values that are separated by semicolons(','). An example is given below.

$value1,value2,value3,value4,value5$

How do I put each of these values in a variable?

Comment: Do you want to cut the string into a `string[]` or create 5 separate `string` properties?

Comment: @Aars93 5 separate string variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Split comma-separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571841/split-comma-separated-values)

Comment: @SeM It is a slightly different question because the dollar signs have to be removed too.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, trim dollar (`$`) character from your input string and then split it by comma (`,`),

```
string str = "$value1,value2,value3,value4,value5$";

string[] values = str.Trim('$').Split(',');  //<= You can add ".ToArray()" at the end for your understaning.
```

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]

Then you can easily get each of your string in above array to separate string variable,

```
string value1 = values[0];
string value2 = values[1];
string value3 = values[2];
string value4 = values[3];
string value5 = values[4];
```

If your values are undetermined then you can simply use foreach loop to access each value like,

```
foreach(string value in values)
{
    //Do code with each value
}
```

Comment: ToArray can be removed. Split already returns a string array.

Comment: @Booser, Yes I write this for OP's better understanding purpose. but now I think It can be remove.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var str = "$value1,value2,value3,value4,value5$";
var arr = str.Replace("$", "").Split(',');
var s1 = arr[0];
...
var s5 = arr[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "$value1,value2,value3,value4,value5$";
str = str.Trim('$'); //removes the '$' characters
string[] array = str.Split(','); //creates an array containing 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a duplicate post but here is the quick answer.

```
string str = "$value1,value2,value3,value4,value5$";
string[] vals = str.Split(','); // splits the strings 
foreach(string value in vals)
{
  string parsedVal;
  if(value.Contains(',') // when split , commas will remain, if it exists we remove
  { 
    parsedVal = value.Trim(',');
  }
  else 
  {
    parsedVal = value;
  }
  //your value is assigned here
  //yourVal = parsedVal;
}
```