# Split a string to get separate email IDs in the string

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a string that contains email addresses like this :

```
string emailIDs = "xyz@gmail.com;abc@yahoo.com;frog@gmail.com;whyme@hotmail.com;"
```

I want to add these emails in List.
I tried splitting it at ';' but this creates an extra record in the list which causes a null exception.
I want to split and add this to my List without any extra record. Please let me know how can I achieve this in c#?

I am trying like this:

```
List<string> To = new List<string>(emailIDs.Cc.Split(new[] { ";" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Following is the result:
[image]

I am trying to remove this extra record at the end be cause Cc contains only two records:
[image]

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571841/split-comma-separated-values) , just a different seperator

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to get rid of blank entries when splitting.

See documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netframework-4.8

Example:

```
var list = emailIDs.Split(new[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Edit:

I think that the string you posted `"xyz@gmail.com;abc@yahoo.com;frog@gmail.com;whyme@hotmail.com;"` does not match the actual string you are passing to `String.Split()` method. Looking closely at the end of `email.Cc`, it contains whitespace at the end, generating a non-empty but blank string that will not be removed by `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

What about trimming that whitespace before?

```
var list = emailIDs.TrimEnd().Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: @Divya this works

Comment: No this does not. If it works I would have accepted this answer.

Comment: Anyways thanks for your answers.

Comment: I updated my answer. Thanks for the additional debug info, I think it's settled now.